# How to define a variable in RPM specs?

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

How to define a variable in RPM specs?
I have 14 folders to create in the RPM and I am creating by following command:

```
mkdir -p /opt/{Folder,Names,Are,Pretty,Cumbersome}
```

My plan is to declare a array variable for all the folders.

Answer (score 5):

In a spec file it is called a macro:

https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/macros.html

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/#_global_preferred_over_define

Each section is just a shell script so you can use normal shell variables. But, it does not survive past the end of the section. So if you want to use something in more than one section you need to use macros.

Comment: How can I define a macro? I have 10 folders and I want to put it in an array. Is it possible using an array macro?

Comment: Nope. In spec macro can be just integer or string. And it is always better to assume it is string.